# Should I use HTTPS within a docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is there any **technical** reason for using HTTPS between services in a Docker Swarm?

I am leaning on *NO* because the services and networks are isolated within the swarm (provided I don't expose the port)

The only technical reason I can think of is HTTP/2 is theoretically faster than plain HTTP for certain scenarios, but the cost of setting that up on a spring-boot system is the need for SSL certificate management (even self signed) and setting up APR for Tomcat, but is it really worth it?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#encrypt-traffic-on-an-overlay-network If you have your overlay network set to use encryption (or if it only goes over trusted infrastructure), HTTP is fine.

Comment: this should move to "software engineering" I think can a moderator move this?

Answer (score 1):

Secure your external communications into your swarm behind a secure proxy. Inside the swarm keep the overhead, complexity, etc. down by **NOT** using SSL/TLS.